# How to solve the stylesheets problem with React?

Tags: django, reactjs, sass

I'm doing my project with React.js I have three scss files in my react code  login.scss, dashboard.css and one main scss file named as index.scss.

I have one common style in my index.scss file and I imported both scss files in index.scss. But my styles are overriding in my pages so my design is not coming properly. How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that index.scss is your default style while dashboard.scss and login.scss are your more specific stylesheets. Therefore, given a conflict between index.scss and either of the other sheets, you want the specific stylesheets to be given precedence. If this is the case, you need to `@import index.scss` to the other sheets.

CSS reads top-down, so the sheet at the bottom, i.e. the sheet **importing** the other sheet will be given precedence. Any classes, tags, etc with the same properties in both index.scss and dashboard.scss would be assigned the property from dashboard.scss if dashboard.scss contains @import.

For example:

index.scss

```
.some-class {
   color: red
}
```

dashboard.scss

```
@import index.scss
.some-class {
   color: blue;
}
```

In this case, an element with .some-class would have a blue font.

Alternately, you can include each sheet in the html page in `<link>` tags, with index.scss placed at the top, as the same top-down reading of CSS applies in the HTML.

If there is anything in index.scss that you never want overwritten, you can apply `!important` to that rule. However, this should be avoided whenever possible, and ideally you would only write things in dashboard.scss that you wouldn't want overwritten by index.scss.